# Adding porter stemmer module to drupal

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-7, porter-stemmer, acquia

I am new to drupal but was able to install acquia-drupal 7 with the microsoft web platform installer. I am trying to add the porter stemmer module but no matter what version I choose, I get this error

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in DrupalLocalStreamWrapper->mkdir() (line 639 of C:\Users\myuserid\Documents\My Web Sites\acquia-drupal7\includes\stream_wrappers.inc).
Unable to create directory 'temporary:'
```

How do I get it properly installed and stop this warning?

Comment: is there a way to add modules through the microsoft webmatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My installation with Microsoft Web Installer was not completely successful. I reinstalled using bitnami and now, I can add ALL THE MODULES.